# BSOD: 0x7F on XP

Tags: windows, bsod

The machine in question is a Dell PP22L laptop.  After logging on, the system will act normally, but slowly, for about 5 minutes before going to a BSOD with the following details: (shown by using [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html))

[image: BSOD 0x7F]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to get a kernel dump and use WinDbg.exe to get the stack trace and find out what kernel mode code was involved in the crash. Most likely it is a driver.

To properly diagnose this error you need to configure your machine to create a proper  Kernel Memory Dump (not a mini dump) and make sure your page file is large enough to hold it (physical ram + 1mb).

Once you have a proper dump, you can use the downloadable [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) to install WinDbg (pronounced wind-bag by the cool people). Debugging kernel dumps is not for the faint hearted. [Here is a guide](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/easywindbg.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

From [TROUBLESHOOTING WINDOWS STOP MESSAGES](http://aumha.org/a/stop.php#0xf4):

> 0x000000F4:
>   CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION
>
> One of the many processes or threads
>   crucial to system operation has
>   unexpectedly exited or been
>   terminated. As a result, the system
>   can no longer function. Specific
>   causes are many, and often best
>   resolved by a careful history of the
>   problem and the circumstances of the
>   error message. One user, who
>   experienced this on return from
>   Standby mode on Win XP SP2, found the
>   cause was that Windows was installed
>   on a slave drive; compare [KB
>   330100](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;330100).

If this doesn't help, please supply additional information:

- Are there any error messages in the Error Log?
- Have you added/replaced any hardware just before this started?
- Have you installed any software or drivers just before this started?
- You might run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to check the computer memory

Answer (score 0):

I have had 2 pc's go through my shop in the last 2 weeks with the same bsod.  One had a faulty hp printer driver causing the issue, a quick removal and re-installation of the software and driver resolved it.  The other had some minor partition problems that were resolved by running a [5 stage check disk](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/how-to-use-check-disk-in-windows-vista/), the guide is for vista but the steps are the same in xp anyway.

Past that some further internet research had another 2 computers, one fixed his issue by replacing the bios battery (unfortunately not easy on a laptop).  The other resolved the problem by running [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso)   and discovering a faulty memory module.

Please run some tests and tell us if you find anything.

Good Luck!